# How to show specific lines of github repo in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, github

I have GitHub code and I want to show specific lines as a snippet in WordPress.
I tried all the plugins, and all of them show the entire file, not the specific lines I want
As an example of what I need to show:

```
https://github.com/nkmk/python-snippets/blob/028c2bcd15e7c776c445ed39e6513801450ed2dc/notebook/datetime_isoformat.py#L1-L8
```

I want to embed a code snippet from line 1 to 8 only in the WordPress post. How?

Regards,